# gcc is not comparing double type variables correctly?

Tags: gcc, floating-point, double

I'm not even sure I am asking a question, I find a "round-about" way this time, but... it took me days to realize this was the problem and... well, some other time I might not be able to just go around it... Has anyone else come to this? When comparing double type variables that are actually equal the result is ">"...

```
 printf("compare: %ld ?? %ld\n", (double)( radii(nowX,nowY)*irange2 ),(double)(Rad2*irange2)); getchar();
 if( (double)(radii(nowX,nowY)*irange2)<(double)(Rad2*irange2) ) printf("*** < ***\n"); 
 if( (double)(radii(nowX,nowY)*irange2)>(double)(Rad2*irange2) ) printf("*** > ***\n");
 if( (double)(radii(nowX,nowY)*irange2)==(double)(Rad2*irange2) ) printf("*** == ***\n")
 printf("SECOND = %d\n", ((double)(radii(nowX,nowY)*irange2))<= ( (double)(Rad2*irange2)
```

output:

```
compare: 1509949.440000 ?? 1509949.440000
*** > ***
SECOND = 0
```

---

```
 printf("compare: %ld ?? %ld\n", (long)( radii(nowX,nowY)*irange2 ), (long)(Rad2*irange2)); getchar();
 if( (long)(radii(nowX,nowY)*irange2)<(long)(Rad2*irange2) ) printf("*** < ***\n");
 if( (long)(radii(nowX,nowY)*irange2)>(long)(Rad2*irange2) ) printf("*** > ***\n"); 
 if( (long)(radii(nowX,nowY)*irange2)==(long)(Rad2*irange2) ) printf("*** == ***\n")
 printf("SECOND = %d\n",  ((long)(radii(nowX,nowY)*irange2))<= ( (long)(Rad2*irange2) ) ); getchar();
```

output:

```
compare: 1509949 ?? 1509949

*** == ***
SECOND = 1
```

Comment: This is a well known problem with floating point arithmetic.  Search for 'What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating Point Arithmetic' on either SO or any other search engine of your choice.  You will find out all you need to know.  The hard part is going to be finding the best duplicate question for this.

Answer (score 2):

The issues here are that floating-point arithmetic is used to do approximate arithmetic, so it gets results with various errors, and that you did not display the complete values of the numbers.

When displayed fully, the numbers are seen not to be equal.

Comparing for equality is not the guilty operation here. Nearly all functions fail to give correct results when given incorrect inputs. For example, if you calculate the square root of a value that would be zero or positive if computed exactly but is slightly negative due to previous rounding errors, then you get an exception for taking the square root of a negative number.

Similar problems occur when rounding approximate results, when subtracting approximate results (which is notorious for increasing the magnitude of relative errors), and other functions. **All** operations with floating point, not just comparing for equality, should be used with consideration for the fact that results are approximate (unless very carefully designed).

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because, depending on the calculation, the double values may differ very slightly. Checking for equality is therefore not recommended. Instead, check if the two doubles are *very* close to eachother. See also [this link](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/floating-point-arith.html) for an explanation.

**EDIT:** Just to clear this up: this is true for all floating-point types, as this is inherent to the way they are stored.

Comment: Thank you, all, so much!
I didn't have this problem before - and, hm, I had used the '=='... sometimes... with floats / doubles - not a lot, I suppose, and I guess I was just lucky, but thank you so much - now I know it's not just some strange behavior on this particular machine (as I initially suspected) and won't risk of getting into some big mess!
Again, thank you!

Comment: @KatiAvramova, please accept this answer by clicking the checkmark on the left. This will mark this question as resolved.